# How to create a .crt file by android studio inside row folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a. crt file in order to type functions in it but I don't know steps to create one of this type I created a row folder, but I couldn't create a CRT file inside it.

Comment: Why don't you use simple explorer?